# Issues embedding Firebase inside other framework

Tags: firebase, carthage

[image]

We have our own swift framework `REFFramework` that is using carthage to import Firebase (analytics and firestore). This is the cartfile in `REFFramework`:

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseFirestoreBinary.json"
```

The `REFFramework` is used in the `app` also using carthage to import it.
In addition the `app` itself also imports other modules from firebase (remote config).
This is the cartfile of the app:

```
git ".../REFFramework"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseFirestoreBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary.json"
```

As far as I know carthage is designed to fully support this kind of structure. We use other frameworks also embedded in `REFFramework` like this such as `Alamofire`.
However we notice a crash in the app that does not happen when we remove the Firebase out of the `REFFramework`.
So it's clearly todo with the embedding of Firebase in an intermediate Framework.
The crash is happening in "`0 __pthread_kill`", here is a screenshot of the debugger in xCode 10.3:

[image]

I see a remark in the documentation:

> Note that the Firebase frameworks in the distribution include static libraries. While it is fine to link these into apps, it will generally not work to depend on them from wrapper dynamic frameworks.

Not sure if this is releated to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the Firebase Carthage frameworks include static libraries and can only be linked to other static library frameworks.